# Creating an instance of a type in another assembly with Activator

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to create an instance of type in a referenced assembly

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance("Config", "Config.TypeName");
var RunMethodInfo = obj.GetType().GetMethod("Run"); //null
```

The get method returns null although the run method exists and the activator seems to create the instance, the Run method is public, any idea why the GetMethod returns null?

Comment: try `obj.GetType().GetMethods()` and see what's returned...

Comment: What does `Run` look like? Is it an instance method? What parameters?

Comment: You'll have to share parts of that referenced assembly to help you out with this. The first argument to `activator.createinstance` should be the assembly name: the physical file name. 2nd argument should be the exact type. Check msdn for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d133hta4

Comment: thanks all for the help, i figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to call Unwrap() Things work as expected now

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance("Config", "Config.TypeName").Unwrap();
var RunMethodInfo = obj.GetType().GetMethod("Run");
```